# How to prevent to edit post parameter values via HTTP header

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to disable the editing the post parameters via `HTTP` headers.

For example by using `"Tamber Data" (Which is one of the Firefox addon)`, we can edit the post values in `header parameter`, then submit the form, and also the values are saving in my database. How can i prevent this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. A client can send anything it wants. Only thing you can do is to check if the values make sense.

Comment: You could calculate a checksum over the data before submitting it and check that on the server side.

Comment: Only issue with @Quagaar 's suggestion is that the sum would be calculated client side, so again the "evil person" at the client end could modify it.  jornane has the right idea - just verify what you are inserting

Comment: @ivanivan: right, the evil person could figure out how the checksum has to be calculated, but it would be quite some effort. The problem I see with jornane's answer is that it could be quite hard to tell what values make sense. Furthermore, why shouldn't the modified data make sense too?